# Linking out to URL directly from PHP search query

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a search bar on my page that is searching my database for values.

`$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Name, Company, Type FROM database WHERE Name LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";`

What I want to do is whenever I get only one result back, I want the search to automatically link to the corresponding webpage (which is site.com/display.php?name=$name&type=$type).

Something along the lines of:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$name     = $row['Name'];
$type    = $row['Type'];

    if ($numrows == 1){
      // Automatically go to the url:
      //site.com/display.php?name=$name&type=$type      
    }
```

Once again, I want to know how to link directly to the page from the search bar -- click submit and if there is only one result, redirect to the specified url.

Any ideas? I've spent the last hour browsing Google and cannot find anything useful.

**To be clear, I am not looking for the header("location:") function**
I need it to be similar to the facebook search - you get results in the drop down, you press enter, and it takes you to the page.

Page structure / my code: http://pastebin.com/RhHL8bHa

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: "I've spent the last hour browsing Google and cannot find anything useful." --- give us examples of search queries you used.

Comment: 1. Redirecting search query to url php
2. going to link after php search 
3. ways to get php to link to a page based on search results

Comment: In regards to your edit, is this search being done via. AJAX?

Comment: Then you'll probably want js. I've added the tags for you.

Comment: @BadWolf - No, See my other comment

Comment: @relentless - That was what I kind of discovered during my search -- I'm not familiar with js at all so I was hoping to do it in php, but thanks for adding the tags.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the code for the page? I'm not entirely clear on how exactly this page is structured.

Comment: "1. Redirecting search query to url php 2. going to link after php search" --- oh. Do you seriously think that redirecting after search differs from redirecting after login? Don't treat programming as a set of recipes for solving huge tasks, but the opposite: every task consists of small subtasks that should be solved separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `header("Location:");`. Note that you CANNOT output anything to the page before calling header or it won't work. Make sure you don't have any whitespace before your first php tag.

```
if($numrows == 1) {
  header("Location: http://site.com/display.php?name=".$name."&type=".$type);
  exit;
}
```

Alternatively you can print some javascript which will perform the redirect.

```
if($numrows == 1) {
      echo "<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = 'http://site.com/display.php?name=".$name."&type=".$type."'</script>";
}
```

Comment: Note 2: it makes no sense to output anything at all when you're redirecting, either before or after `header('Location: ...);`

Comment: That was my immediate thought, but I can't make it work with search (I have to show content on the page)

Comment: @user2419123 Does your search involve submitting a form? If so, just run this query at the top of the page before you output anything. If you redirect then it will go to the new page, if not then you can display the results afterwards.

Comment: I have the page set up so that won't work. My form code keeps you on the same page:
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_Self']; ?>"

Comment: But submitting the form still results in the page reloading. If you check to see if there is `$_POST` data at the top of the page and run the query there you should be able to redirect before you print anything. Barring that, can you please post the rest of your code so that we can get a complete picture of what your'e doing?

Comment: @user2419123 short of re-structuring your entire page you should probably do this with javascript. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($numrows == 1){
   $server=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  // Automatically go to the url:
  header("location:http://$server/display.php?name=$name&type=$type");      
}
```